# To show $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\ln x$ by using DCT?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I know $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\log x＝０$ can be proved by using l'Hospital, but
I heard that this statement can also be shown by using dominated convergence theorem.
Hint says we use the function $f（t,x）＝1[x,1]（t）x/t$.
Could you give me the process of applying DCT to this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: We have that the given limit is equivalent to$$\lim_{x\to0}\int_0^1\frac{x(x-1)}{(x-1)t+1}\mathrm{d}t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} I_{(x,1)} (t) \frac  x  tdt \to \int_0^{1} dt=0$ by DCT because $I_{(x,1)} (t) \frac  x  t \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$ for every $t$ and $0 \leq I_{(x,1)} (t) \frac  x  t \leq 1$. The constant function $1$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ so DCT is applicable.  Of course, $\int_0^{1} I_{(x,1)} (t) \frac  x  tdt = -x \ln x$ so we get $x \ln x \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry,but what is a sequence of measurable function here?What is a character parametrizing the sequence? x?

Comment: Proving that $x \ln x \to 0$ is equivalent to proving that $x_n \ln x_n \to 0$ for every sequence $x_n \to 0$. So the sequence of functions can be taken as $f_n(t)=I_{(x_n,1)} (t) \frac  {x_n} t$. @bellow

Comment: Do you say given limit is equivalent to lim[n→∞]∮[0,1]（-f（t,xn）dt ?

Comment: @bellow Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you! Why we us indicator function? What is the merit（or necessarity） to use indicator function ?And, in your answer, why ’of course' ∮I（x,1）（t）x/tdt＝-xinx?

Comment: Sorry,but is ∮ here a lubesgue ones? or Riemann one? The same thing?thank you

Comment: On $[x,1]$ we are integrating a continuous function. The function is both Riemann integrable and Lebesgue integrable and its Riemann integral is equal to its Lebesgue integral.

Comment: we integrate on [0,1], how can I explain the value integrated on {0,1] is same as on [xn,1]?

Comment: All integrals are actually over $(0,1)$ but f or fixed $x$ the function we are integrating is $0$ for $t <x$ so it is enough to integrate from $x$ to $1$.  @bellow

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $0<x<1$ $$|x\log x| = \left|\int_x^1\frac{x}{t} \, {\rm d}t\right| \leq \int_x^1\frac{x}{t^{3/2}} \, {\rm d}t = 2\sqrt{x}(1-\sqrt{x}) \, .$$

Comment: How can I proceed from here? Is integral used here is lubesgue's or Riemann's ? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "proceed from here". I think you are done. Just take the limit $x\rightarrow 0$. Even though I considered it as an ordinary Riemann-Integral, I presume it can be considered as either type of integral for fixed $x$.

Comment: Thank you I understood.. Where did you use lubesgue dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: There is only 1 inequality.